# Adding multiple images into a view from photo library - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, photosui

I want to add images from phone's photo library into a collage layout that I made. First I made the collage layout as a separate view in SwiftUI called CollageLayoutOne.

```
import SwiftUI

struct CollageLayoutOne: View {
    
    var uiImageOne: UIImage
    var uiImageTwo: UIImage
    var uiImageThree: UIImage
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.gray)
            .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
            .overlay {
                HStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.gray)
                        .overlay {
                            Image(uiImage: uiImageOne)
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        }
                        .clipped()
                    VStack {
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(Color.gray)
                            .overlay {
                                Image(uiImage: uiImageTwo)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            }
                            .clipped()
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(Color.gray)
                            .overlay {
                                Image(uiImage: uiImageThree)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            }
                            .clipped()
                    }
                }
                .padding()
            }
    }
}
```

Then I have a separate view (PageView) where I want to show the CollageLayoutOne view and it also hosts the button to get to the image library.

```
struct PageView: View {
    
    @State private var photoPickerIsPresented = false
    @State var pickerResult: [UIImage] = []
    
    var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
        ScrollView {
            if pickerResult.isEmpty {
                
            } else {
                CollageLayoutOne(uiImageOne: pickerResult[0], uiImageTwo: pickerResult[1], uiImageThree: pickerResult[2])
            }
            
            
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
        .navigationBarTitle("Select Photo", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: selectPhotoButton)
        .sheet(isPresented: $photoPickerIsPresented) {
          PhotoPicker(pickerResult: $pickerResult,
                      isPresented: $photoPickerIsPresented)
        }
      }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    private var selectPhotoButton: some View {
      Button(action: {
        photoPickerIsPresented = true
      }, label: {
        Label("Select", systemImage: "photo")
      })
    }
    
}
```

My problem is that for some unknown reason the app crashes every time I select the photos and try to add them. If I do `pickerResult[0]` for all three it works just fine, but displays only the first selected photo on all 3 spots. Also if I start with all 3 as `pickerResult[0]` and then change them to `[0], [1], [2]` while the preview is running it doesn't crash and displays correctly.

I'm just starting with Swift and SwiftUI, so excuse me if it's some elementary mistake. Below I am also adding my code for PhotoPicker that I got from an article I found.

[image]

PhotoPicker.swift:

```
import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI

struct PhotoPicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
  @Binding var pickerResult: [UIImage]
  @Binding var isPresented: Bool
  
  func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController {
    var configuration = PHPickerConfiguration(photoLibrary: PHPhotoLibrary.shared())
    configuration.filter = .images // filter only to images
    if #available(iOS 15, *) {
        configuration.selection = .ordered //number selection
    }
    configuration.selectionLimit = 3 // ignore limit
    
    let photoPickerViewController = PHPickerViewController(configuration: configuration)
    photoPickerViewController.delegate = context.coordinator
    return photoPickerViewController
  }
  
  func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) { }
  
  func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
  }
  
  class Coordinator: PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
    private let parent: PhotoPicker
    
    init(_ parent: PhotoPicker) {
      self.parent = parent
    }
    
    func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
      parent.pickerResult.removeAll()
      
      for image in results {
        if image.itemProvider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {
          image.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { [weak self] newImage, error in
            if let error = error {
              print("Can't load image \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else if let image = newImage as? UIImage {
              self?.parent.pickerResult.append(image)
            }
          }
        } else {
          print("Can't load asset")
        }
      }
      
      parent.isPresented = false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`image.itemProvider.loadObject` is an asynchronous function, and it loads images one by one.

When the first image is processed, you add it to `pickerResult` and your `pickerResult.isEmpty` check becomes `false`, but your array contains only one item so far.

The safe thing to do here is to check the count:

```
if pickerResult.count == 3 {
    CollageLayoutOne(uiImageOne: pickerResult[0], uiImageTwo: pickerResult[1], uiImageThree: pickerResult[2])
}
```

Also, in such cases, it's a good idea to wait until all asynchronous requests are complete before updating the UI, for example, like this:

```
var processedResults = [UIImage]()
var leftToLoad = results.count
let checkFinished = { [weak self] in
    leftToLoad -= 1
    if leftToLoad == 0 {
        self?.parent.pickerResult = processedResults
        self?.parent.isPresented = false
    }
}
for image in results {
    if image.itemProvider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {
        image.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { newImage, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Can't load image \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else if let image = newImage as? UIImage {
                processedResults.append(image)
            }
            checkFinished()
        }
    } else {
        print("Can't load asset")
        checkFinished()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
estruct PHPickerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
@Binding var images: [UIImage]?

func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> PHPickerViewController {
    var config = PHPickerConfiguration()
    config.filter = .images
    config.selectionLimit = 6
    let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
    picker.delegate = context.coordinator
    return picker
}

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: PHPickerViewController, context: Context) { }

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
    let parent: PHPickerView
    
    init(_ parent: PHPickerView) {
        self.parent = parent
    }
    
    func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true)
        
        let imageItems = results
            .map { $0.itemProvider }
            .filter { $0.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) }
        
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
        var images = [UIImage]()
        
        for imageItem in imageItems {
            dispatchGroup.enter()
            
            imageItem.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { image, _ in
                if let image = image as? UIImage {
                    images.append(image)
                }
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
        }
        
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            self.parent.images = images
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: It could help readers if you [edit] your answer and add an explanation how your answer solves the question.

Comment: This solution does not work, i was writing similar code.  The code will lose the Self reference when the picker dismisses